# Dynamic Autocomplete Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am having trouble regarding dynamic data being passed on my autocomplete angularjs directive which is made of jquery-ui autocomplete. Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="peopleApp">
    <div ng-controller="indexController">
        <label class="input-group-addon input-label">Search:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-form" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search here..." auto-complete names="names">
        <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', []);


peopleApp.controller('indexController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $controller){
    $http.post(domainName+url)
    .then(function(response){
        data = response.data.data;
        $scope.names = data.map(function(obj){ var rObj = []; rObj.push(obj['rank_code']); rObj.push(obj['rank_description']); return rObj; });
    });

    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.names = ["hnnnnn", "billlll"];
    }
});


peopleApp.directive('autoComplete', function(){
    return {
        scope: {names: '='},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // alert(JSON.stringify(element));
            attrs.$observe('names', function(val){
                // scope.info = val;
                alert(val);
                scope.names = val;
            });
            element.autocomplete({
                source: scope.names,
                select: function() {
                    // alert('dean');
                    // iElement.trigger('input');
                },
                // Sets the min of characters before activating dropdown
                minLength:2
            });
        }
    }
});
```

First of all the data that is fetched from the API does not integrate in the autocomplete. Second I want it that when I press a button the $scope.names that will change will also be integrated on the autocomplete

Comment: Do not mix libraries from `jquery` with `angular`. It is in principle possible to do, but sometimes it is easier to find a library for `angular`. Like this [ngAutocomplete](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete)

Comment: So do you have a solution on the source being dynamic or not?

Comment: The solution used by the dynamic source exist. For example [angular strap typeheads](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads).

Comment: Can you provide a code? Because I am quite certain that this can be done. It's just I'm new to this angularjs

Comment: Do you see a link? There are good example.

Comment: The content on the link is so many. There's a lot of section on it. Maybe you can provide or point out the specific solution that you are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution with jQuery `autocomplete`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/swfjT/4345/).

```js
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
  $scope.addName = function() {
    $scope.names.push($scope.name);
  }
}

angular.module('MyModule', [])
.controller('DefaultCtrl',DefaultCtrl)
.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      uiItems: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      scope.$watchCollection('uiItems', function(val) {
        console.log(val);
        iElement.autocomplete({
          source: scope.uiItems,
          select: function() {
            $timeout(function() {
              iElement.trigger('input');
            }, 0);
          }
        });
      });

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
  <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
    <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected"> selected = {{selected}}
    <br>
    <input placeholder="add name" ng-model="name">
    <button ng-click="addName()">
      Add name
    </button>
    <pre>{{names|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks man! 'scope.$watchCollection' really did the trick but can you explain what that is for? and the flow of the syntax?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). Or see [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm). You will need it in the future.